# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "database_class" does not exist

Tags: python, django

I have been recently working on a project that just parses data from csv file to the django models stored in a PostgreSQL database. Running "makemigrations" and "migrate" are fine as long as I comment out the parse function but when I do runserver with the function now uncommented the error "django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "database_class" does not exist".

Code:

```
import csv
import os
import time
import json
from django.db import models
from django.core import serializers
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Individual class model
class Class(models.Model):
    prefix = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    ID = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    name = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    description = models.TextField(null=False, blank=False)
    HI = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    CI = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    DI = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    fall = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    spring = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    summer = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False, default=0)
    pathways = ArrayField(models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True), default=list, size=10, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

#Parse through CSV file
def parse():
    # Get the absolute csv file
    csvFile = os.getcwd() + "/" + "HassPathways.csv"

    # Open the file
    with open(csvFile, 'r') as file:
        # Read it and note the delimeter
        file_r = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')

        # Loop through teh columns
        for col in file_r:
            # Skip the empty empty data (work on more debugging so we can handle errors, or maybe create a Google app script that handles the errors for us... more details on that later)
            if (col[0] == "" or col[6] == "" or col[1] == "ID"):
                continue

            # Make sure the class object doesn't already exist
            if (len(Class.objects.get(prefix__exact = col[0].strip(), ID__exact = col[1].strip() ,name__exact = col[2].strip())) == 0):
                print("Creating " + col[2].strip())
                # Create class
                created = Class.objects.create(
                prefix = col[0].strip(),
                ID = col[1].strip(),
                name = col[2].strip(),
                description = col[3].strip(),
                HI = col[4].strip(),
                CI = col[5].strip(),
                DI = col[6].strip(),
                fall = col[7].strip(),
                spring = col[8].strip(),
                summer = col[9].strip())

                created.pathways.append(col[10].strip())

                # Save class
                created.save()

            else:
                print("Adding to " + col[2].strip())
                result = Class.objects.get(prefix__exact = col[0].strip(), ID__exact = col[1].strip() ,name__exact = col[2].strip())
                if (col[10].strip() in result.pathways):
                    continue
                else:
                    result.pathways.append(col[10].strip())
                    result.save()
         
#Main code start
parse()
print("Done!")
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you. I would move the `parse` function to a helper file to clean things up.

Then in your helper you can do `from .models import Class.

Secondly I'd rename Class to something else.

Thirdly, make sure that there's an `__init__.py` file in the same folder as your models.

Comment: I made the helper file but the problem still exists. __init__.py is there but there is nothing in it

Comment: That's correct. `__init__.py`s are generally empty. It's used to mark a directory as a Python package.

Comment: My migrations folder was missing thank you for the help!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!